# What is the correct function to use when saving HTML data to a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I know this is a rather basic question, but what is the correct function to use against form input fields when HTML is inserted into a MySQL database? (mysql_real_escape_string, htmlentities, etc.)

Also, which function should be used when printing the value from the database in a text field, html page, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) when inserting in the database, and [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) before printing.

Comment: @user576875, I'm using mysql_real_escape_string() when saving the form and htmlspecialchars() when printing the value in an input field (for editing purposes), but a backslash "\" is appearing before any quotes ". How can I prevent this from happening while at the same time, making sure the backslash appears if the user intentionally added it to the input field?

Comment: Your inputs are getting escaped twice before you are inserting them into the database.  If you're using PHP, make sure that magic quotes are turned off: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: I'm running MAMP and have PHP 5.3.2 enabled. I searched for "magic" and the only thing that came up is: ; Magic quotes ; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \'). magic_quotes_sybase = Off. When I clicked on the link to magicquotes you provided, it said it was depricated in PHP 5.3. What setting should I change since magic quotes is depreciated and magic_quotes_sybase is already set to Off?

Comment: I added that to my ini file and restarted Apache, but backslashes are still appearing before "s in my input fields (even after deleting them and saving the update). Any other ideas?

Comment: are you modifying the right php.ini file ? look at phpinfo()'s output

Comment: Yes, here are the settings from phpinfo(): magic_quotes_gpc Off Off magic_quotes_runtime Off Off magic_quotes_sybase Off Off

Comment: Are you using addslashes() or anything like this on the data before/after mysql_real_escape_string() ? are you speaking of newly submitted data, or data already in the db ? With magic quotes disabled, I would say that the slashes come from the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PDO and prepared statements, you don´t have to worry that much about the data you are inserting in the database.

About the output, it depends what you need: If it´s for real html output, you cannot use `htmlentities` as the output will not be html anymore.